# CSS: How to change position : relative to fixed and preserve "left" and "top" values

Tags: css, angular

I am writing a dragDirective in Angular2. Elements are arranged using ng-for and default to position:relative. To move the element I need to change the position attribute to fixed. This causes a sudden jump in the element position.

How do I resolve this.

Template-

```
<li *ngFor = "#el of dragZoneElems; #idx = index">
  <h1 [dragResponder] = "true">{{el.first}} {{el.last}}</h1>
</li>
```

Directive-

```
    this._mousedown.switchMap((mdwnEvn, i) => {
        this.DisableSelection();
        mdwnEvn.preventDefault();
        this._messageBus.dispatch("dragStart", this._elem);
        return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
            observer._next({
                prevx: mdwnEvn.x - this._elemBounds.left - window.pageXOffset,
                prevy: mdwnEvn.y - this._elemBounds.top - window.pageYOffset
            });
        });
    }).switchMap((offSet, i) => {
        return this._mousemove.flatMap((mmoveEvn, i) => {
            mmoveEvn.preventDefault();
            this.DisableSelection();
            return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
                observer._next({
                    left: mmoveEvn.x - offSet["prevx"],
                    top: mmoveEvn.y - offSet["prevy"]
                });
            });
        }).takeUntil(this._mouseout).takeUntil(this._mouseup);
    }).subscribe({
        next: pos => {
            this.SetPosition(pos);
        }
    });
}
```

SetPosition Function-

```
SetPosition(pos : Object){
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elem.nativeElement, "position", "fixed");
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elem.nativeElement, "left", (pos["left"] - this._margin[1]).toString() + "px");
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elem.nativeElement, "top" ,  (pos["top"] - this._margin[0]).toString() + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fixed position is related to the window position, if you need to keep the same position you have to calculate the windows width and height and add or reduce them by your values.

Comment: How do I get the orginial position(set by ng-for) relative to window ?

Comment: Yes there are many properties for the windows, document, and page

take a look into http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to find a single property that changes when changing position from relative to fixed. However the element still shifts position. I need to know which property value changes so that I can offset the current position accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The Question ended up being irrelevant. The jump was happening because I was not reinitializing the bounds on click.