# Accessing class data from callback

Tags: typescript, angular

The directive below registers a listener with MessageBus class. Which executes the registered callback when the dispatch function is called. I need to access the "dragZoneElems" from within the callback and perform operations on it. Please advice on how to do this. At present it says dropZoneElems = undefined, since this data is outside the callback scope. However the data is present and is not undefined.

```
export class DragZoneDirective implements OnInit{
   private _messageBus : IMessageBus

   @Input() dragZoneElems: Object[];
   constructor() {
      this._messageBus = MessageBus;
   }

   ngOnInit(){
    this._messageBus.listen("dragStart", function(val) {
        console.log("DragStart", this.dragZoneElems);
        let index = this.dragZoneElems.indexOf(val);
        if(index > -1)
            this.dragZoneElems.slice(index, 1);
    });
    this._messageBus.listen("dragStop", function(val) { console.log("DragStop"); });
   }
 }
```

Message Bus-

```
static dispatch(event: string, info?: any): void {
     this.listeners
        .forEach((l) => {
           if (l["event"] === event) {
               l["cb"](info);
           }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use arrow functions to be able to use the lexical this (it corresponds to your component instance):

```
this._messageBus.listen("dragStart", (val) => { // <--------
    console.log("DragStart", this.dragZoneElems);
    let index = this.dragZoneElems.indexOf(val);
    if(index > -1)
        this.dragZoneElems.slice(index, 1);
});
```

See this link for more hints about the lexical this of arrow functions:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: Hi Thierry, Its my good luck today that you are around. Thanks. I need help with another question could you take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178359/css-how-to-change-position-relative-to-fixed-and-preserve-left-and-top-va/36178475?noredirect=1#comment59992216_36178475